# Numpy optimizing multi-variate Gaussian PDF to not use np.diag

Tags: python, numpy

I have this numpy code for calculating the PDF of multivariate Gaussian

```
def multinormalPDF(self, X, mu, sigma):
    '''
    Args:
         X: NxD
         mu: 1xD
         sigma: 1xDxD
    Returns:
         N dimensional array with prob dist of N data
    '''
    det = np.linalg.det(sigma)
    
    const = 1.0/ (math.pow((2*np.pi), float(len(mu))/2) * math.pow(det, 1.0/2))
    diff = np.matrix(X - mu)
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)       
    result = np.diag(np.exp(-0.5 * (diff * sigma_inv * diff.T)))
    return const * result
```

As you can see there's a glaring issue here "np.diag(np.exp(-0.5 * (diff * sigma_inv * diff.T)))", which is calculating the square matrix then getting the diagonals. This obviously will overflow on memory when X is very large like let's say X is 100000 points each if dimension size 3. So in that case X is 100000x3 sigma is a 3x3 and mu is 1x3. How can I optimize this code so I don't need the np.diag and it'll run for larger numbers of data points as in larger X? How can I just calculate the diagonal values rather than calculating the whole matrix?

Comment: Could you annotate te code, noting array shapes? I'm not at my computer,so can't do it now.  I'd especially like to see the `diag` expression written out in `einsum` style.

Comment: @hpaulj done! Hopefully you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
np.diag(np.exp(-0.5 * (diff * sigma_inv * diff.T)))
```

That's an elementwise `exp`?

```
(N,D) * (D,D) * (D,N) => (N,N)
np.einsum('ii', np.einsum('ik,kl,lj', diff,sigma_inv, diff.T))
np.einsum('ik,kl,il->i', diff,sigma_inv, diff)

diff[:,None,:]@sigma_inv[None,:,:]@diff[:,:,None]
```

Experiment small N, e.g. 4 or even 2

### testing

```
def foo1(X, mu, sigma):
    det = np.linalg.det(sigma)
    const = 1.0/ (math.pow((2*np.pi), float(len(mu))/2) * math.pow(det, 1.0/2))
    diff = X - mu
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    result=diff[:,None,:]@sigma_inv@diff[:,:,None]
    result=result.squeeze()   # (N,1,1) => (N,)
    result = np.exp(-0.5 * result)
    return const * result

def foo2(X, mu, sigma):
    det = np.linalg.det(sigma)
    const = 1.0/ (math.pow((2*np.pi), float(len(mu))/2) * math.pow(det, 1.0/2))
    diff = X - mu
    sigma_inv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    result=np.einsum('ik,kl,il->i', diff, sigma_inv[0], diff)
    result = np.exp(-0.5 * result)
    return const * result
```

sample with N=2

```
In [240]: X=np.arange(1,7).reshape(2,3)
In [241]: mu=np.ones((1,3))*.1
In [242]: sigma=np.eye(3).reshape(1,3,3)
```

Values:

```
In [243]: multinormalPDF(X,mu,sigma)
Out[243]: array([6.52996667e-04, 3.35351164e-17])

In [244]: foo1(X,mu,sigma)
Out[244]: array([6.52996667e-04, 3.35351164e-17])
In [245]: foo2(X,mu,sigma)
Out[245]: array([6.52996667e-04, 3.35351164e-17])
```

times (modest improvement due to small N)

```
In [246]: timeit multinormalPDF(X,mu,sigma)
157 µs ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [247]: timeit foo1(X,mu,sigma)
73.9 µs ± 17.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [248]: timeit foo2(X,mu,sigma)
82 µs ± 19.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

With N=1000 the times are

```
42.1 ms 
281 µs 
274 µs
```

for N=100000

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 74.5 GiB for an array with shape (100000, 100000) and data type float64
19 ms 
13.4 ms
```

So eliminating the `diag` does solve the memory issue, as well as being faster.